# how to run my eclipse J2E project using IP address instead of localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, server, jboss7.x

I am currently developing a java project using Eclipse. The sever is **jBoss v7.**

I use **localhost:8080** to run my project but now I want to use my own **IP address** to run it instead of using localhost, so that my partner can access to my project  from another PC .

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run your jboss with

```
run.bat -b <your_ip_address>
```

or

```
standalone.bat -b <your_ip_address>
```

Comment: yes I have seen this answer before, but how can run it ? Like do I need to edit the codes inside the file or something ?  Thanks

Comment: @linnndaaa No you do not need to change anything. You only have to start your jboss on command line with the ip address as argument. Then the jboss will listening on your external ip-address.